# Tooltip in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a DataGridView in a Winforms application containing a collection of items. Each item has an image and various other details. I know it is possible in WPF, but can you get a tooltip to display an image and a more structured set of details then just plain text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to draw it yourself, look at `ToolTip.OwnerDraw`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw.aspx